# How to get Type from PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, event-handling

I will explain what I am trying to do first.

I have a quite a few of DataGrids and each DataGrid use different classes for there data type and instead of subscribing an Event handler for each one, I was hoping to make a generic event handler and get the type from from the `sender` object.

> `I am using EntityFramework Database First`

One example of one of the classes:

```
public partial class StaffData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public long ID { get; set; }        
    public string StaffNameFirst { get; set; }
    public string StaffNameSecond { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }       
}
```

My ViewModel:

VeiwModelBase holds the `INotifyPropertyChanged` data.

```
public class MasterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public static ObservableCollection<StaffData> MasterDataBinding
    {
        get { return _mMasterData; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == _mMasterData)
                return;

            _mMasterData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MasterViewModel()
    {
        _mMasterData.CollectionChanged += master_CollectionChanged;
    }


    public void master_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //asign PropertyChanged event here 
    }

    private void master_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Type foo = sender.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var newRowData = sender as foo;                    
        SaveData(newRowData);
    }

    private static void SaveData(object newRowData)
    {      
        Type foo = newRowData.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var originalData = dataBaseEntities.foo.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == newRowData.ID);
        entities.Entry(originalData).CurrentValues.SetValues(newRowData);
        dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();        
    }
}
```

These are the two methods above which I can't seem to figure this out, I have tried countless ways using `Getype` with not much success (I left my last attempt in hopefully to illustrate what I am trying to do). I have commented out how I am normally going about this:

```
private void master_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Type foo = sender.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var newRowData = sender as foo; 
    //var newRowData = sender as StaffData             
    SaveData(newRowData);
}

//private static void SaveData(StaffData newRowData)
private static void SaveData(object newRowData)
{      
    Type foo = newRowData.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var originalData = dataBaseEntities.foo.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == newRowData.ID);
    //var originalData = dataBaseEntities.StaffData.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == newRowData.ID);
    entities.Entry(originalData).CurrentValues.SetValues(newRowData);
    entities.SaveChanges();        
}
```

When trying to use the variable as a type I get this error,

> Error CS0118  'foo' is a variable but is used like a
>   type

Is there a way to get the type when you don't know which datagrid will implement the `PropertyChanged` event and use it so as you can make a generic event handler for all the `Datagrid` controls?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but can solve the error with the `foo` type like this: `var newRowData =Convert.ChangeType(sender, foo);`

Comment: The sender's type is always `StaffData` or a potential type derived from StaffData.

Comment: @Clemens, I posted one class to illustrate what I am trying to do, what happens when it is is a different class (Type), especially when I hope to use just one event handler for all the different Classes (types).

Comment: Is my question unclear as to what I am trying to do? Thanks

Comment: I still don't see it clear. For what you are trying to do, what i suggest in my previous comment might work, but i think what you want is [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: @Pikoh, I failed, my brain is fried, see my comment to Clemens. Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I really understand your question, but you could check the type of the `sender` argument at runtime and call an appropriate method like this:

```
private void master_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is StaffData)
    {
        DoSomething((StaffData)sender);
    }
    else if (sender is SomeOtherData)
    {
        DoSomething((SomeOtherData)sender);
    }
    ...
}

private void DoSomething(StaffData data)
{
    ...
}

private void DoSomething(SomeOtherData data)
{
    ...
}
```

However, I'd prefer to have different PropertyChanged handler methods for different sender types.

Comment: I have about 20 classes, I was hoping to avoid this. Cheers

Comment: I want to get the `type` at runtime, so I can use it to query the database or update and new data.

Comment: You can of course get the type at runtime with `sender.GetType()`, but what to do then? You still have to have different methods that handle different types. You might perhaps use the `GUID` or `FullName` property of the Type as a key.

Comment: Well, I feel rather stupid now. I was so caught up in making a generic event , that I lost sight of the forest for the trees. You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get the type inside the propertyChanged event handler but you can get the property name from PropertyChangedEventArgs.
Something like:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == "SomePropertyName")
            {
                //... do your stuf
            }
        }
```